# node.js create 'server side socket' for bots chat (chatscript)

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, chat

We're using Socket.io's socket.emit and socket.on methods to manage chatroom messages.

```
var io = require('socket.io') // socket.io.js
var sio = io.listen(server);
app.set('socket io', sio);
sio.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {    
  socket.on('broadcast-message', function(chatroomIdStr, username, message) {
  });
}):
```

On the client side we have :

```
  socket.emit("broadcast-message", chatroomId, username, message);
```

We're using Chatscript and wanted to use the same schema for sending bot messages.
However, when trying this on the server side (app.js) :

```
var socketbot = io.connect('localhost')
socketbot.emit("broadcast-message", chatroomId, username, message);
```

We get:

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'connect'

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Are you using socket.io from node to connect to another location ?

Comment: we use socket.io to emit messages to users (sockets) and eventually window.location os res.render users to other locations.

Answer (score -3):

I'm working on something similar and believe the answer is that you need to use 'socket.io-client' in your nodejs bot rather than 'socket.io'.

'npm install socket.io-client' got me something I could work with, but I'm still debugging what the bot client should look like.